# UILabel: Using the userInteractionEnabled method on a label

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

I am wondering if anyone has used the userInteractionEnabled method on a UILabel to allow the label to act like a button (or just to fire off a method).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

Update (4/30/09 @1:07pm) Clarification:  I have a standard InfoButton and next to it I want to place a label with the text "settings" and I would like the label to function like the button (which flips over to a settings screen.  So, basically I need to tie the already defined showSettinsView to the "infoLabel" label; a user clicks on the infoButton or infoLabel and the method fires off.

The infoButton is already working and is using an IBAction to trigger the method. I would like to know how to wire up the label to implement the same method. That is all.  Cheers!

Comment: You'll get more useful responses if you clarify your question: What do you need help with specifically? What have you tried that didn't work, and/or what exactly do you want to do that you don't know how to accomplish?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`userInteractionEnabled` is not a method but a property. But I think you will want to set this to `YES` to allow events to get through to the `UIView` superview.

What you might want to do is override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method of the `UIView` that contains your `UIButton` and `UILabel` subviews.

Within this method, test if any of the `UITouch` touches fall inside the bounds of the `UILabel`.

That is, does the `CGPoint` element `[touch locationInView]` intersect with with the `CGRect` element `[infoLabel bounds]`? Look into the function `CGRectContainsPoint` to run this test.

If so, then fire off an `NSNotification` that calls the same `IBAction` selector as the `UIButton`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll go ahead and try it and see what I can do.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Another solution could be to use a `UIButton` with its type set to custom, instead of a `UILabel`. This way your second button will look like a `UILabel`, and you can configure it to trigger the `showSettingsView` method.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex Apr 30, '09 and my proposal is just an addition to it, if you don't want to go with a UIButton. The way I solved it was by creating a UILabel through

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
    ...
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
    [self addSubview: label];
}
```

then you can override the touches* methods like touchesBegan, touchesEnded with something like

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      if([touch view] == label) {
          NSLog(@"I've been touched");
       }
   }
```

Comment: I wonder why i have a similar code like you, but mine is not firing touchesBegan