# how can i make a button such that user only see the text on it but not the button iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

how can i make a button such that user only see the text on it but not the button in iphone sdk ?
i tried to lower its alpha value but even then it appears a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just don't want to see the rounded rectangle of the button then set the button type to custom.

Comment: i did it but it still shows button shadow on its back i want that user just see the text on it but should not appear to be a button still clickable

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808679/uilabel-using-the-userinteractionenabled-method-on-a-label) by using a UILabel instead of a UIButton. This does not answer directly to your question, as setting a custom type should and since it does not can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Create your button of type UIButtonTypeCustom and add:

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use a custom button......

```
UIButton *custBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCusttom];
[custBtn setText:@"Sarabjit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubView:custBtn];
```